# Delete folder from storage0 - android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I cant delete the folder in storage. This is my code

```
  File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/sdcard/folder" );
                if (dir.isDirectory())
                {
                    String[] children = dir.list();
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                    {
                        new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it

but first you need to have this permission in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and then

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sdcard/folder"); 
if (dir.isDirectory()) 
{
String[] children = dir.list();
for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
   new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
}
}
```